# rgb value to r,g,b values in php

Tags: php, colors, rgb

I've done some code in php, an exercise which was about implementing a class representing a color.

The class is made so that I can receive either 3 'red', 'green' and 'blue' values, which doesn't bother me, but I could also receive an 'rgb' value.

In the end, here's the code which did the trick to handle the 'rgb' case:

```
if (array_key_exists('rgb', $kwargs))
{
$this->red = intval($kwargs['rgb']) >> 16 & 255;
$this->green = intval($kwargs['rgb']) >> 8 & 255;
$this->blue = intval($kwargs['rgb']) & 255;
}
```

However, I really don't understand why we need the '& 255'.

Why can't I simply use a right shift alone to convert the value back?

I mean, if I receive: 00000001 00000001 00000001 in 'rgb', if I >> 16, I'm supposed to get 1, if I >> 8, I'm supposed to get 1 as well, right?

I looked up the '&' operator, and it says that it's supposed to act as a mask (if I understood the concept of mask correctly), but after the mask operation, I'm still with the same result as before (1,1,1). I don't get why this '& 255' is necessary (I tried without it, it doesn't work).

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to answer me.

Comment: Does your code even works as you expect it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `& 255` is to make sure you only receive the value within this mask (which are the first 8 bits set). This is to make sure you only get the "R", the "B" or the "G" component, and not anything else.

Example:

```
 RGB:       11001100 10101010 11110000

 RGB >> 16: ???????? ???????? 11001100
     & 255: 00000000 00000000 11111111
            --------------------------
                              11001100  (red)

 RGB >> 8:  ???????? 11001100 10101010
     & 255: 00000000 00000000 11111111
            --------------------------
                              10101010  (green)

 RGB      : 11001100 10101010 11110000
     & 255: 00000000 00000000 11110000
            --------------------------
                              11110000  (blue)
```

So what these lines do in essence is "shifting" the value you want to the beginning and only fetch the part you are interested in (the first 8 bits) by masking it.

Comment: If OP receives his data in this format: `00000001 00000001 00000001` I don't think his code works as he wants it to. (But I really like your example and it explains it very well, whats going on)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are flawed

`00000001 00000001 00000001` right shifted by 8 gives `00000001 00000001` which isn't the result that you want.... masking that by `255` (`11111111`) sets all bits but those in the least significant byte to 0, giving `00000000 00000001`, which is the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered. I now understand how the mask works.

And to answer Rizier123, yes, the code works, I passed the exercise, I was only asking for explanations, I hate submitting a code where a part of it isn't clear in my mind. I was receiving the data on the form:

"decimal int value" possibly followed by "<< 8" or "<< 16"

I was only using the bit format to explain my example.